# TFS local project can't connect after Url changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

My TFS server was installed into a network wich has a PUlbic IP, It was used to identify my  server something like `http://1.1.1.1:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`.

Due to changes on our infraestructure, this ip changed.  and at my Project the url was updated to. now my url look like this

`http://mydomain.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`

**NO CHANGES WAS MADE AT TFS SERVER**

Now I connect with my new URL and Works fine (at least it connect), but when try to protect my Project (or perform another operation with TFS) , it still point to the old URL and told me that can't reach TFS server.

How can i do to update my Project connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Team Foundation Server Administration Console on the TFS server, you need to change the URLS under Application Tier

It could also be a cache issue in VS, Try clearing the cache here:
C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

Comment: My local URL wasn't changed, Prior to change I'm uisng ``OldUrl`` for Access outside my network. The only thing changed was my public direction.

Comment: Clearing the TFS cache might help. Info on how to clear it [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/08/19/how-to-clear-visual-studio-team-explorer-cache.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if it's something cached locally too.  Are you doing this in IE or Visual Studio?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez you need to update the *Public URL* on that page.  See  http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-09-88-27-25/Exposing-Team-Foundation-Server-to-the-Internet.docx

Comment: @malexanderDirectly from visual studio 2012 update 4

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez I added the location of the team explorer cache above, it's worth looking at. back it up and wipe it, see if that clears it up

Comment: @malexander You ara right, it was a cache issue, drop the cache and now everything goes fine. You save my day. tks.